# git merge origin/branch vs. merge branch locally

Tags: git

What is the different between when I merge the `origin/branchX` into `branchY` and merge `branchX` into `branchY`?

Comment: They might point to different things e.g. if Git shows your branch as behind. Note as well that your `origin/branchX` might not be up-to-date either e.g. if you haven't run `git fetch` in a while.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`origin/branchX` is a remote tracking branch, and gets updated with changes from the remote repository every time you do a `git fetch`.  On the other hand, `branchX` is your local version of this branch.  `branchX` may be out of sync with `origin/branchX` which in turn may be out of sync with what is actually on the remote repository.

Hence the difference in doing a merge will depend on the differences in the various incarnates of `branchX`.  If you want to merge the very latest `branchX` into your `branchY` then you should do the following:

```
git fetch origin          # update remote tracking branchX
git checkout branchY      # switch to branchY
git merge origin/branchX  # merge
```

If you want to also update your local `branchX` in the process, you could do this:

```
git checkout branchX
git pull origin branchX
git checkout branchY
git merge branchX
```

However, you might have the need to merge your local copy of `branchX` into `branchY` without synching either branch with the remote.  This would be a typical use case if, for example, new changes came into `branchX` on the remote and you did not want to bring them into `branchY` just yet.  In this case you would perform the merge like this:

```
git checkout branchY
git merge branchX
```

Answer (score 1):

When merging the remote branch - you are retreiving it with all remote changes that have been applied to it by other devs, but that might not yet be on your local branch (though without your local changes that have not yet been pushed to remote branch)

And when merging local branch you are merging it with all changes that you have done locally that have not yet been pushed to remote branch, but without all remote changes that have been applied to it by other devs, but that might not yet be on your local branch.

```
         -*-*-* branchX 
*-*-*-*-/-*-*-*-*-* Origin/branchX
```

Imagine these are your local and remote branches, you have commited changes twice to your local branch and somebody has added 5 commits and pushed to repo, so you don't have those 5 on your local branch yet.