# What's the difference between "git merge foo" and "git merge origin/foo"?

Tags: git

What's the difference between:

```
(master) ~ $ git merge foo
```

and

```
(master) ~ $ git merge origin/foo
```

When I did the first one, it told me "already up-to-date", with the second one, I got a bunch of updates and comment to save in my default editor (vim). Like if it was two different branches. But if I do `git branch -r`, I have:

```
  origin/dev
  origin/foo
  origin/master
```

If I do `git branch`, I have:

```
* dev
  foo
  master
```

I'm a bit confused with the `origin/` prefix.

Comment: `origin` is the common name of the remote repo, you can have branches in local or remote repos.

Comment: foo is local where you can work, origin/foo is the remote tracking branch (tracking foo on origin).

Comment: `origin/foo` - usually it is remote branch; and `foo` - is local branch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git merge origin/branch vs. merge branch locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36282085/git-merge-origin-branch-vs-merge-branch-locally)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that all `git merge` operations work with a *commit* (as found by its hash ID). Try running `git rev-parse foo` and then `git rev-parse origin/foo`; this may provide enlightening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command:

```
git merge foo
```

says to merge into the currently checked out branch the *local* branch called `foo`.  By "local," I mean the local version of the `foo` branch on which you might have been doing your work.

The command:

```
git merge origin/foo
```

says to merge into the currently checked out branch the remote tracking branch called `origin/foo`.  `foo` and `origin/foo` might be pointing to the same commit, or they might not.  For example, if you have recently fetched, then it's possible (or even likely) that `origin/foo` would be more recent than the local `foo` you have on your machine.

By the way, if you're wondering what the utility of the remote tracking branches is, these branches are local branches on your machine which exist as proxies for the true remote branches in the repository.  Git operations primarily operate locally, and this distributed support is one reason which makes Git powerful.

For added information, suppose you wanted to push your local `foo` branch to the remote, via:

```
git push origin foo
```

In this case, `origin` actually refers to the remote Git repository (e.g. something like GitHub or Bitbucket), and `foo` refers to the local branch you want to push.

Comment: “foo and origin/foo might be pointing to the same branch” No, they are different branches. They might be pointing to the same _commit_.

Comment: @matt Yeah...you're right, I changed my wording.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `git merge foo`, you try to merge with your local branch, so it's already up-to-date.

When you do `git merge origin/foo`, you try to merge from remote branch.

Answer (score 0):

`git merge origin/foo` will merge remote branch into your current local active branch.
Usual workflow is that one merges local branches into local branches. So do the following:

`git checkout foo` - it will switch to local `foo` branch;

`git pull origin` - if `foo` branch tracks remote `origin/foo` branch - it will pull all remote updates to local branch;

`git checkout master` - switch to local `master`;

`git merge foo` - finally you will merge `foo` branch into `master`.